# initialise multiple variables at once in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I would like to initialise multiple variables in one go without writing lots of code. I know there is a simple way to do it in python but am not sure in R. FOor instance

```
BHPO <- array(0,length(b))

BHPR <- array(0,length(a))

BHP <- array(0,length(a))

BHR <- array(0,length(a))

NORM <- array(0,length(a))
```

all in one line, please can someone help with this. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, the first length is supposed to be length(a)

Comment: You can do `BHPO <- BHPR <- ...... <- NORM <- array(0, length(a))`. Is it what you want ?